# adding a drawn circles Objects to an Arraylist

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I created an Arraylist of objects (Circles). I added a mouseclick event and so once I click in the panel, a circle will be drown and stored in the arraylist. I am stuck and can't think of a way around my code... I would appreciate some hints that could help me solving my problem.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Circle extends JFrame
{

    private JPanel panel;
    private  ArrayList <Circle> circle;

    public static void main(String[]args)

        {

        setTitle("Drawing Circles");
        // Set the size of the window.
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        // Specify an action for the close button.
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // set the Frame's layout
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        // Add the panels to the frame's content pane.
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        // Display the window.
        setVisible(true);

        circle = new ArrayList<Circle>();
        }

    public Circle()
        {
        panel.addMouseListener(new ClickingLitener());
        }




    private class ClickingLitener implements MouseListener
    {

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {
            circle.add(new Circle());

            // somehow I need to call panel.paintComponent ... right ?
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: first thing is assign the "new Circle()" to a local variable. Do everything you want to do with it, including the paint etc, and then add the local circle to the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Circle` class extends JFrame. You can't add or paint a JFrame on a JPanel so your basic approach is flawed.

If you want to do custom painting to draw a `Circle` on a panel then you need to store information about the `Circle` that you want to draw. Then in the paintComponent() method of the panel you iterate through the ArrayList and paint all the circles. When you add a new Circle to the ArrayList you just invoke repaint() on the panel.

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for working examples of this approach. The code adds "Rectangles" to the panel, but you should be able to change the code easily enough to add circles.